# Before useSelector call state initialize undefined or loading forever

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, state, redux-thunk

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cc90n.jpg)

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();
const { _id } = useParams();
const admin = useSelector((state) => state.SelectedAdminReducer);

const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
const [data, setData] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  dispatch(SelectedAdmin(_id));
  setData(admin)
  setLoading(false);
}, []);

return <>{loading ? <h3>Loading...</h3> : <div>{data.name}</div>}</>;
```

Comment: of course it's undefined before you set it in the useEffect with the dispatch. Also, it looks like your useEffect dependency array is missing "SelectedAdmin" which is undefined in this screenshot.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.